# Java create PDF from template: Apache FOP vs?

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have to create a pdf from Java, I would like to create it from a template instead of create it using java code ex:

```
document.addLabel("a pdf..")
```

I've seen that I can do it with Apache FOP that use the XSL-FO for the template, does anyone know a free graphical designer for the XSL-FO? I've found just https://www.ecrion.com/Products/XFDesigner/StartTrial.aspx this one.

Or are there some alternatives to Apache FOP?
Thank you!

Comment: It's sad when a perfectly good question is closed because it may "solicit debate". I would be really interested in peoples answers to this so for me it's really constructive i.e. serving a useful purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recomend you the combination of [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) and [JODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter). JODReports it's a solution to generate reports from ODT templates, so it is easy to design templates using LibreOffice. Later, you can transform the reports (in format .odt or .doc) to PDF.

Comment: interesting thing! How can I generate a template from LibreOffice? IS there a guide to do it?

Comment: solved...it is like a freemarker template...fantastic! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of a free one - Oxygen and XML spy have far from free options.
you can also use iText, which I believe is not free anymore, and there are quite a few open source libraries round a google away. Personally have always done the XSL-FO by hand so can't comment on the editors (quite easy if you have not heavy requirements)

Depending on your use, and complexity there are other options, such as creating html and then processing it with wkhtmltopdf or something

Answer (score 0):

There's always TeX (which has http://tex.stackexchange.com). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210029/pdf-libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at XDocReport where you can create your template from [odt (report)](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/ODTReporting) or [docx (report)](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReporting) and it provides too full Java converter (odt->pdf, odt-xhtml, docx->pdf, docx->xhtml converters):

- Pros with those XDocReport full Java converter is that you need not to install a OpenOffice/LibreOffice (like JODConverter) to manage conversion. More you work with streaming mode (not need to generate a temporary file)
- Cons with those XDocReport full Java converter is that renderer could be less good than OpenOffice/LibreOffice